# selenium webdriver support for IE10 Metro?

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver, internet-explorer-10

Is there any support for IE10 Metro in selenium webdriver? By default the tests run on Desktop mode. Any way to test in Metro mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no support for automating using the Metro interface at the time of this writing. Sorry. Selenium is an open-source project, however, and I'm sure the developer of the IE driver would be happy to review any patches or solutions you might come up with.