# Selenium WebDriver Support for IE metro mode

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Is there any way of writing automation on IE10 metro mode with the help of Selenium WebDriver? I came across the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067061/selenium-webdriver-support-for-ie10-metro) but the question and answer both are dated 25th Feb, 2013. Is there any support available as of now?
If not, how can I go about doing automation on IE10 metro mode?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver
launching of IE browser (32 bit or 64 bit) depends on what version of IEdriverserver.exe you use. Not sure if there is an IEdriverserver which will launch IE in metro mode.

But I found out 1 answer on stackoverflow where you can change the settings of your IE browser in desktop mode, like those on Metro mode.
[Detect Metro UI Version of IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751479/javascript-detect-metro-ui-version-of-ie)
Check out Bert Lamb's answer on this page. (you can go through the whole conversation its might be helpful :))